# Why I started get 403 error after update OctopusPush step to v6?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, octopus

I have azure pipeline which pushes build packages to octopus. I had OctopusPush@4 step which work correctly. When i just updated version to 6 OctopusPush@6 I started get 403 error. Can someone help with this?